# "|=" operator caches static field value?

Tags: c#, operators

I was having an interesting bug with changes not being registered. The fix was unusual. The first code works fine, while the second one - doesn't.

https://rextester.com/PIRZFJ12810

```
globChanged = false;

bool tmp = target.Inspect();
globChanged |= tmp;  
 
if (globChanged) Debug.LogError("Works!");
```

This one doesn't work:

```
globChanged = false;

globChanged |= target.Inspect();

if (globChanged) Debug.LogError("Works!");
```

I think I have a suspicion. `globChanged` is a public static field. The `target.Inspect();` actually returns False. But internally it sets `globChanged = true` when changes are made. I think the operator "|=" evaluates the value of `globChanged` before the `Inspect();` function was called. And I actually tested this - at the end of `target.Inspect();` the `globChanged` is True.

Also:
Doesn't work:

```
  globChanged = globChanged || pgi.Inspect();
```

Works:

```
globChanged = pgi.Inspect() || globChanged;
```

To clarify. Doesn't work means that It returns False when globChanged was set True. pgi.Inspect(); is executed every time and globChanged  is False at the start.

Comment: Conditional OR operator `||` doesn't evaluate right-hand operand, if left-hand is `true`. Therefore `pgi.Inspect();` isn\t called here `globChanged = globChanged || pgi.Inspect();`, when `globChanged` is `true`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski but we´re talking about `|`, not `||`. The former isn´t short-circuiting, the latter is.

Comment: @HimBromBeere the last snippet is showing usage of `||` : `globChanged = globChanged || pgi.Inspect(); `

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski But globChanged is False. Then it becomes True when pegi.Inspect(); is executed, but turns false again as soon as |= operator is executed.

Comment: as from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-or-operator-) `|` isn´t short-circuitung, so the right operand should be evaluated anyway. For `||` on the other hand things get different - the order of operands is important in this case.

Comment: @IuriiSelinnyi Please provide a [repro]. In [this example](https://rextester.com/HTIT91866), `globChanged` evaluates to `true` in both cases.

Comment: @41686d6564   Done. Added to my post.

Comment: Validity aside, setting `globChanged` directly from within `Inspect()`, as you say you do, would make the code extremely confusing, if you ask me.

Comment: @IuriiSelinnyi Okay, I see what you mean now. Well, that's not a bug and is very expected behavior. In the first case, you call `Inspect()` which changes the value of `globChanged` to `true` and then returns false, so when you use `|`, you're basically evaluating `true | false` (which evaluates to `true`). In the second case, you're evaluating `false | Inspect()`, which means `false | false`. It doesn't matter that `Inspect()` changes the value of `globChanged` since the left side is evaluated _before_ calling `Inspect()`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError  I agree. Not the best design choice. That thing is basically SetDirty(); It is done automatically if you edit anything. But you can also return True (something was changed). I probably will change it to void Inspect();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `value |= DoSomething` is nothing but this:

```
_value = _value | DoSomething
```

In your first example you set `tmp` to whatever `Inspect` returns - `false`. However that method also sets `globalChange` to `true`. **Afterwards** `globalChange` is evaluated in the next line. It is now `true`, which results in `true | false`.

The second example is a bit more tricky.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators):

> The | operator evaluates both operands even if the left-hand operand
> evaluates to true, so that the operation result is true regardless of
> the value of the right-hand operand.

As mentioned here **both** expressions are evaluated from the **left to the right**. So first `_gloablChange` is evaluated, which is `false`, as of its initial value. **Afterwards** the second operand is evaluated. It also returns `false`, even though it has some side-effect. That side-effect however is irrelevant as the value of `globalChange` already was evelauted **before**. Thus `false | false` just returns `false`.

The `||`-operator on the other hand is short-circuiting, which means the right part is only evaluated if the left one is `false`.

Comment: Your explanation works but the code that you have shown will return true because `static bool DoSomething => _value = true;` will return true. Using the function that was shared in the question, _value will be set to false as has been explained in your answer.